# Sort Map of String,List<String> by Value List size

Tags: java

I need to sort the hashmap based on value List size and its' not working. I've written my custom comparator. For example hashmap is as follow:

```
Test1-a,b
Test2-c,d,e
Test3-f
Test4-d,g,h,i
Test5-p,b
```

After sorting it should look like this:

```
Test3-f
Test1-a,b
Test5-p,b
Test2-c,d,e
Test4-d,g,h,i
```

Sorting the keys based on value list size in ascending order. I wrote this code and it's not working:

```
List<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> list =
        new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>() {
    public int compare( Map.Entry<String,List<String>> o1,
                        Map.Entry<String,List<String>> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().size().compareTo(o2.getValue().size() );
    }
});
```

Comment: "Intellij seems to throw error." Yes? What's the error? You know, knowing the error is very important. In fact, that's the first thing you should have done, you should have copied the error on your clipboard and googled it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not compilabe, because `List.size()` returns an (unboxed) `int` .. we cannot invoke "methods" on that.

Instead try:

```
Collections.sort( 
  list,
  // when java >= 8, we can save all the "decoration" (anonymous class), and "lambda" instead:
  (o1,o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.getValue().size(), o2.getValue().size())
);
```

Javadoc (`Integer.compare(int x, int y)`): https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)

[Its implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) looks as simple as:

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
  return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Comment: But more alarming is, that your program does output though uncompilable!:)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the above answer together with your code, you could do

```
        List<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> list = 
        m.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.getValue().size(), e2.getValue().size()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
```